# Book on numerical analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, book-recommendation, numerical-optimization

Is numerical analysis by James Scarborough good enough for starting  on numerical analysis?

Comment: Probably not. According to a [review in 1967](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2004209) it's a book from the 1930s, that was not appropriate even back then for computer applications. Considering the progress that was made in numerical computing since then, it would harldy be usable even for introductory numerical analysis.

Comment: For instance, having a look at the table of contents (I don't give the link as it's probably a violation of copyright, but you'll be able to find a copy online), there is nothing on linear systems beyond Gauss pivoting: no LU, no QR, and since the conjugate gradient method was invented in the 1950s, don't count on it either. Nothing on FFT for the same reason (1965). And these are basic methods.

Comment: Another point: usually, "advanced numerical analysis" is highly specialized, and you will not find everything in one book. It's not like introductory level, where everyone learns more or leass the same basic methods. If you need an advice, you will have to be more specific: what are you willing to learn, for what kind of application? It could be for instance PDE for engineering, optimization and linear algebra for statistics, wavelets, or many other topics, each having a long bibliography.

Comment: I am a student of pure mathematics and learning numerical analysis by self study. I already read some indian author.

Comment: Ok, then you probably need to start with good introductory material. I would tend to suggest [Bulirsch & Stoer](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Numerical-Analysis-Applied-Mathematics/dp/144193006X). A bit dated, but it should be appealing to a "pure math" student.

Comment: Another one: [Theoretical Numerical Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Theoretical-Numerical-Analysis-Functional-Mathematics/dp/1441904573/) by Atkinson and Han. I don't own this one, but judging from the table of contents, it's mainly geared towards partial differential equations and integral equations, with relatively high level mathematics (there is a chapter on Sobolev spaces for instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already write in the comment the book is old, so it is not the best choose.

There are a lot of books in numerical analysis so this answer is quite opinion based, and and the suggestion depends a lot on the person's background. (I was a math student)

The first thing to take in account is that generally for specific a arguments there are specific books.
I suggest these titles who are quite central as augments, so in case you can use them  for further reference.

*Atkinson, Kendall; Han, Weimin*, [**Theoretical numerical analysis. A functional analysis framework**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-0458-4), Texts in Applied Mathematics 39. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4419-0457-7/hbk; 978-1-4419-0458-4/ebook). xvi, 625 p. (2009). [ZBL1181.47078](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1181.47078).

*Quarteroni, Alfio; Sacco, Riccardo; Saleri, Fausto*, Numerical mathematics, Texts in Applied Mathematics. 37. New York, NY: Springer. xx, 654 p. (2000). [ZBL0957.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0957.65001).

*Stoer, J.; Bulirsch, R.*, Introduction to numerical analysis. Translated from the German by R. Bartels, W. Gautschi and C. Witzgall., Texts in Applied Mathematics. 12. New York: Springer-Verlag. xiii, 660 p. (1993). [ZBL0771.65002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0771.65002).

I found these books useful when I was student (and also after).

Comment: Stoer/Bulirsch is a very good book! It is one of the few excellent German books on numerical mathematics that has been translated to English.